# Intersection of finite measure coverings of the rationals?

Tags: real-analysis

If we enumerate the rational numbers, let $A(n)$ be the set of real numbers obtained by surrounding the $k$th rational with a closed interval of length $n^{-k}$. This gives a covering of the rationals by sets of finite measure.

In his article "A beginner's guide to countable ordinals," in the section on Borel Sets, Gowers claims that the intersection of the $A(n)$'s is not just all the rational numbers. Why is this the case?

Comment: I'm confused. So if $\{ q_{i} \mid i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$, then is $A(n) = \bigcup \limits_{k = 1}^{\infty} D(q_{k},\frac{1}{2}n^{-k})$, where $D(q_{k},\frac{1}{2}n^{-k})$ is the closed disk of radius $\frac{1}{2}n^{-k}$ with center $q_{k}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: I think you can use the Baire category theorem.  There may be an easier way

Comment: How does the result follow from BCT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $A(n)$ is open and dense. The same is true of $B(n):=A(n)\setminus \{q_1,\dots,q_n\}$, where $(q_n)_n$ is an enumeration of the rationals.

Now Baire's category theorem shows that
$$
\bigcap_n B(n)
$$
is a dense (hence nonempty) subset of the reals.

This implies the claim (why?).